# What's the use of constraint in Gradle dependencies resolution?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, constraints, gradle-dependencies

There is a library i.e. `io.github.elye:simplekotlinlibrary` with version 1.0.0, 2.0.0 and 3.0.0.

The `io.github.elye:easyandroidlibrary:1.0.0` contain `io.github.elye:simplekotlinlibrary:1.0.0`

The `io.github.elye:simpleandroidlibrary:2.0.0` contain `io.github.elye:simplekotlinlibrary:2.0.0`

So in my Gradle, if I have

```
    implementation ('io.github.elye:easyandroidlibrary:1.0.0')
    implementation ('io.github.elye:simpleandroidlibrary:2.0.0')
    implementation ('io.github.elye:simplekotlinlibrary:3.0.0')
```

It will auto-resolve to `io.github.elye:simplekotlinlibrary:3.0.0` for the project including the transitive dependencies.

However, with https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html#sec:adding-constraints-transitive-deps, it states that the `constrains` also force an upgrade of dependencies to the indicated version `3.0.0`.

```
    implementation ('io.github.elye:easyandroidlibrary:1.0.0')
    implementation ('io.github.elye:simpleandroidlibrary:2.0.0')
    implementation ('io.github.elye:simplekotlinlibrary')

    constraints {
        implementation('io.github.elye:simplekotlinlibrary:3.0.0') {
            because 'testing force upgrade'
        }
    }
```

From my understanding, the above two examples will produce the same result. Seems like `constraint` has no real use? How does `constraint` differ from the differ auto dependencies resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in the above example they are the same.

However in the event that the top level project doesn't need `io.github.elye:simplekotlinlibrary`, using `constraint`, one can still force all transitive dependencies to **at-least** the version indicated by the `constraint` as shown below.

```
    implementation ('io.github.elye:easyandroidlibrary:1.0.0')
    implementation ('io.github.elye:simpleandroidlibrary:2.0.0')

    constraints {
        implementation('io.github.elye:simplekotlinlibrary:3.0.0') {
            because 'testing force upgrade'
        }
    }
```

A further detail illustration can be found [here](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/understand-gradle-dependency-resolution-easier-290d81a5db5a?sk=db528d063d97d0cf8323402abbec4d4c)